# How to compile library without packaging IInAppBillingService.aidl

Tags: android, shared-libraries, static-libraries, aidl

I'm writing a library for providing drop-in solution for InAppBilling for Android. I'm looking for ways to publish jar/aar without AIDL files in it. How can I compile/package my library which has dependencies on IInAppBillingService.aidl file, and NOT include "IInAppBillingService.aidl" file in final distribution ? Any thoughts ?